# How to validate a International Securities Identification Number (ISIN) number

Tags: math, financial

If I am not wrong, ISIN numbers last position is a verification digit.
What is the mathematical function that determines its value in function of the first 11 digits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number

> The procedure for calculating ISIN check digits is similar to the "Modulus 10 Double Add Double" technique used in CUSIPs. To calculate the check digit, first convert any letters to numbers by adding their ordinal position in the alphabet to 9, such that A = 10 and M = 22. Starting with the right most digit, every other digit is multiplied by two. (For CUSIP check digits, these two steps are reversed.) The resulting string of digits (numbers greater than 9 becoming two separate digits) are added up. Subtract this sum from the smallest number ending with zero that is greater than or equal to it: this gives the check digit, which is also known as the ten's complement of the sum modulo 10. That is, the resulting sum, including the check-digit, is a multiple of 10.

They have a [good example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number#Examples) too.

Comment: That description has some mistakes:
"...every other digit is multiplied by two". 
As I could find in other references, and checking the examples: Not every other number but alternative digits are multiplied by two.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo: it is perfectly reasonable to construe `every other digit` to mean `alternative digits`.  It's not clear what you think the mistake(s) in the Wikipedia entry are.

Answer (score 10):

Building on the examples of others, here is a C# implementation which will validate both ISINs and CUSIPs (and maybe some other Luhn variations).

Usage:

```cs
foreach (var isin in ValidIsins)
{
    var calculatedChecksum = SecuritiesValidation.CalculateChecksum(isin.Substring(0, 11));
    var actualChecksum = (isin.Last() - '0');
    Assert.AreEqual(calculatedChecksum, actualChecksum);
}
foreach (var cusip in ValidCusips)
{
    var calculatedChecksum = SecuritiesValidation.CalculateChecksum(cusip.Substring(0, 8), true, true);
    var actualChecksum = (cusip.Last() - '0');
    Assert.AreEqual(calculatedChecksum, actualChecksum);
}
```

Implementation:

```cs
public static class SecuritiesValidation
{
    public static int CalculateChecksum(IEnumerable<char> codeWithoutChecksum, bool reverseLuhn = false, bool allowSymbols = false)
    {
        return reverseLuhn
            ? codeWithoutChecksum
                .Select((c, i) => c.OrdinalPosition(allowSymbols).ConditionalMultiplyByTwo(i.IsOdd()).SumDigits())
                .Sum()
                .TensComplement()
            : codeWithoutChecksum
                .ToArray()
                .ToDigits(allowSymbols)
                .Select((d, i) => d.ConditionalMultiplyByTwo(i.IsEven()).SumDigits())
                .Sum()
                .TensComplement();
    }

    public static bool IsChecksumCorrect(string code, bool reverseLuhn = false, bool allowSymbols = false)
    {
        try
        {
            var checksum = code.Last().ToInt();
            return checksum == CalculateChecksum(code.Take(code.Length - 1), reverseLuhn, allowSymbols);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /* Be careful here. This method is probably inapropriate for anything other than its designed purpose of Luhn-algorithm based validation.
     * Specifically:
     * - numbers are assigned a value equal to the number ('0' == 0, '1' == 1).
     * - letters are assigned a value indicating the number 9 plus the letters ordinal position in the English alphabet ('A' == 10, 'B' == 11).
     * - if symbols are allowed (eg: for CUSIP validation), they are assigned values beginning from 36 ('*' == 36, '@' == 37).
     */
    private static int OrdinalPosition(this char c, bool allowSymbols = false)
    {
        if (char.IsLower(c))
            return char.ToUpper(c) - 'A' + 10;

        if (char.IsUpper(c))
            return c - 'A' + 10;

        if (char.IsDigit(c))
            return c.ToInt();

        if (allowSymbols)
            switch (c)
            {
                case '*':
                    return 36;
                case '@':
                    return 37;
                case '#':
                    return 38;
            }
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Specified character is not a letter, digit or allowed symbol.");
    }

    private static bool IsEven(this int x)
    {
        return (x % 2 == 0);
    }

    private static bool IsOdd(this int x)
    {
        return !IsEven(x);
    }

    private static int ToInt(this char digit)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(digit))
            return digit - '0';
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Specified character is not a digit.");
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> ToDigits(this char[] s, bool allowSymbols = false)
    {
        var digits = new List<int>();
        for (var i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var ordinalPosition = s[i].OrdinalPosition(allowSymbols);
            digits.Add(ordinalPosition % 10);
            if (ordinalPosition > 9)
                digits.Add(ordinalPosition / 10);
        }
        return digits;
    }

    private static int SumDigits(this int value)
    {
        //return value > 9 ? ((value / 10) + (value % 10)) : value;
        return ((value / 10) + (value % 10));
    }

    private static int ConditionalMultiplyByTwo(this int value, bool condition)
    {
        return condition ? value * 2 : value;
    }

    private static int TensComplement(this int value)
    {
        return (10 - (value % 10)) % 10;
    }
}
```

It will likely make sense to use checksum validation in conjunction with a regular expression pattern match. These are the regex I use:

ISIN: `^(XS|AD|AE|AF|AG|AI|AL|AM|AO|AQ|AR|AS|AT|AU|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|BJ|BL|BM|BN|BO|BQ|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CC|CD|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK|CL|CM|CN|CO|CR|CU|CV|CW|CX|CY|CZ|DE|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EC|EE|EG|EH|ER|ES|ET|FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|GA|GB|GD|GE|GF|GG|GH|GI|GL|GM|GN|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|ID|IE|IL|IM|IN|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|JO|JP|KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MC|MD|ME|MF|MG|MH|MK|ML|MM|MN|MO|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NC|NE|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NU|NZ|OM|PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|PN|PR|PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SR|SS|ST|SV|SX|SY|SZ|TC|TD|TF|TG|TH|TJ|TK|TL|TM|TN|TO|TR|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UM|US|UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|YE|YT|ZA|ZM|ZW)([0-9A-Z]{9})([0-9]{1})$`

CUSIP: `^[A-Z0-9]{8}[0-9]$`

Comment: Works well for FIGI as well.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you! Note that the ISIN namespace is no longer current. For example the "EU" prefix now exists.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the examples published in Wikipedia, the method is:

1. Replace each letter by its ordinal (A=1, B=2 and so on) plus 9 -> [image]
2. For each digit at an even position starting from the rightmost position ([image]), replace it by the digits of its double (two digits in two vector entries) -> [image];
3. Verification code:

[image]

A possible implementation in JavaScript is:

```
function getVerificationCode(isin)
{
 if(isin.length != 12) return null;
 var v = []; 
 for(var i = isin.length-2; i >= 0; i--)
 {
    var c = isin.charAt(i);
    if(isNaN(c)) //Not a digit
    {
        var letterCode = isin.charCodeAt(i)-55; //Char ordinal + 9
        v.push(letterCode % 10);
        if(letterCode > 9)
          v.push(Math.floor(letterCode/10));
    }
    else
      v.push(Number(c));
 }
 var sum = 0;
 var l = v.length;
 for(var i = 0; i < l; i++)
     if(i % 2 == 0)
 {
    var d = v[i]*2;
    sum += Math.floor(d/10);
    sum += d % 10;
 }
 else
    sum += v[i];
 return 10 - (sum  % 10);
}
```

**EDIT:**  To include @queso updates:

```
function getVerificationCode(isin) {
    if (isin.length != 12) return false;
    var v = [];
    for (var i = isin.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        var c = isin.charAt(i);
        if (isNaN(c)) { //not a digit
            var letterCode = isin.charCodeAt(i) - 55; //Char ordinal + 9
            v.push(letterCode % 10);
            if (letterCode > 9) {
                v.push(Math.floor(letterCode / 10));
            }
        } else {
            v.push(Number(c));
        }
    }
    var sum = 0;
    var l = v.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            var d = v[i] * 2;
            sum += Math.floor(d / 10);
            sum += d % 10;
        } else {
            sum += v[i];
        }
    }
    return (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10
}
```

Comment: For the code above, ISIN XS0977502110 fails looking here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number#External_links I was able to update your code here  http://jsfiddle.net/markbenda/nh2w1Lbh/16/.   Thanks for doing the hard part.

Comment: @Queso I've edited my answer to include your code suggestions. Thanks for the improvements!

Comment: I've diffed these two versions and the non-whitespace/brackets revisions appear to be 1) return `false` instead of `null` on the second line, and

2) return `(10 - (sum % 10)) % 10` instead of  `10 - (sum  % 10)`  in the second-to-last last line, adding an extra mod 10 as the final step.

https://www.diffchecker.com/jEeML1lU

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share my implementation in R. It does not require any specific package.

The mgsub is a support function that allows the substitution of all the characters in the ISIN code in one single command. It is copied from [Replace multiple letters with accents with gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253954/replace-multiple-letters-with-accents-with-gsub)

the `iso3166alpha2$Code` contains the list of countries that  [Grenade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68115/grenade) has listed

The algorithm is implemented in the `isIsin(x)` function, which returns `TRUE` in case of valid ISIN code

```
mgsub <- function(pattern, replacement, x, ...) {
  if (length(pattern)!=length(replacement)) {
    stop("pattern and replacement do not have the same length.")
  }
  result <- x
  for (i in 1:length(pattern)) {
    result <- gsub(pattern[i], replacement[i], result, ...)
  }
  result
}

isIsin <- function (identifier) {

  correctPrefix <- substr(identifier, 1, 2) %in% c(iso3166alpha2$Code, "XS")

  correctLength <- nchar(identifier) == 12  

  correctCharset <- !grepl('[[:punct:]]', identifier)

  if(!correctPrefix | !correctLength | !correctCharset) {
    return(FALSE)
  }

  # replace all character with its equivalent number  
  identifierOnlyNumbers <- mgsub(LETTERS, seq(10, 35), substr(identifier, 1, 11))

  # split the identifier in single digits and reverse its order
  characterVector <- rev(unlist(strsplit(identifierOnlyNumbers, "")))

  # Double every second digit of the group of digits with the rightmost character
  characterVector[seq(1, nchar(identifierOnlyNumbers), 2)] <- 
    as.character(as.numeric(characterVector[seq(1, nchar(identifierOnlyNumbers), 2)]) * 2)

  # Subtract 9 if > 9 (can apply to all since no digit can be greater than 9 before doubling)
  # Add up the digits
  summation <- sum(ifelse(as.numeric(characterVector) > 9, as.numeric(characterVector) - 9, as.numeric(characterVector)))

  # Take the 10s modulus of the sum, subtract it from 10 and take the 10s modulus of the result 
  # this final step is important in the instance where the modulus of the sum is 0, as the resulting check digit would be 10
  correctCheckDigit <- (10 - (summation %% 10)) %% 10 == as.numeric(substr(identifier, 12, 12))

  correctCheckDigit 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, although I needed to use `DescTools` , `data("d.countries")` and I needed to replace `iso3166alpha2$Code` with `d.countries$a2`. Then it works.
https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/DescTools/html/d.countries.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function cusipToIsin($CUSIP, $Country)
{
    if (strlen($CUSIP) == 9) {
        $string = charToCusipBinary($Country) . charToCusipBinary($CUSIP); //Convert any letters to numbers
        $arrayString = str_split($string);
        //check wether string length is even or odd
        if (strlen($string) % 2 != 0) {
            $num = 0;
            foreach ($arrayString as $key => $value) {
                //Collect odd and even characters
                if ($key % 2 != 0) {
                    $values = $value;
                } else {
                    $values = $value * 2; //The key is in odd position, so Multiply by 2
                }
                $sumValue = array_sum(str_split($values)); //Add up the individual digits
                $num += $sumValue;
            }
            $isinCheckDigit = (10 - ($num % 10)) % 10;
            $result1 = strtoupper($Country . $CUSIP . $isinCheckDigit);
        } else {
            $num = 0;
            foreach ($arrayString as $key => $value) {
                //Collect odd and even characters
                if ($key % 2 != 0) {
                    $values = $value * 2; //The key is in even position, so Multiply by 2
                } else {
                    $values = $value;
                }
                $sumValue = array_sum(str_split($values)); //Add up the individual digits
                $num += $sumValue;
            }
            $isinCheckDigit = (10 - ($num % 10)) % 10;
            $result1 = strtoupper($Country . $CUSIP . $isinCheckDigit);
        }
        $Validate = isinValidate($result1);
        if ($Validate == true) {
            $result = $result1;
        } else {
            $result = 'Please check the CUSIP';
        }
    } else {
        $result = 'Please check the CUSIP';
    }
    return $result;
}

function charToCusipBinary($string)
{
    return strtr(strtoupper($string), ['A' => '10', 'B' => '11', 'C' => '12', 'D' => '13', 'E' => '14', 'F' => '15', 'G' => '16', 'H' => '17', 'I' => '18', 'J' => '19', 'K' => '20', 'L' => '21', 'M' => '22', 'N' => '23', 'O' => '24', 'P' => '25', 'Q' => '26', 'R' => '27', 'S' => '28', 'T' => '29', 'U' => '30', 'V' => '31', 'W' => '32', 'X' => '33', 'Y' => '34', 'Z' => '35']);
}

function isinValidate($isin)
{
    if (!preg_match('/^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{9}[0-9]$/i', $isin)) {
        return false;
    }
    $base10 = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 11; $i++) {
        $base10 .= base_convert($isin{$i}, 36, 10);
    }
    $checksum = 0;
    $len = strlen($base10) - 1;
    $parity = $len % 2;
    for ($i = $len; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $weighted = $base10{$i} << (($i - $parity) & 1);
        $checksum += $weighted % 10 + (int) ($weighted / 10);
    }
    return !(bool) ($checksum % 10);
}

echo cusipToIsin('78012KD61', 'US'); //ISIN: US78012KD617
?>
```

Comment: I have created a PHP function based on [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number]
You can give 7 Digit CUSIP number with 2 digit Country code

Comment: Works for me and can not only be used for Cusips but also other identifiers with the relevant adaptions (e.g. rpad)

Answer (score 1):

I share with you a function in Matlab, thanks to **@pablo** and **@queso**.

```
function isISIN = checkISINCode(Isin)
%
%
%
% see:
%   - source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number
%   - source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140753/how-to-validate-a-international-securities-identification-number-isin-number
%
%
    isISIN = 0; 

    if length(Isin) ~= 12
        return;
    end

    v = [];
    for i = (length(Isin)-1):-1:1
        c = Isin(i);
        if isnan(str2double(Isin(i)))
            % from ASCII 
            letterCode = double(upper(Isin(i))) - 64 + 9; 
            v = [mod(letterCode, 10), v];
            if letterCode > 9
                v = [floor(letterCode/10),v];
            end
        else
            v = [int8(str2double(Isin(i))), v];
        end
    end

    sum_ = 0;
    l = length(v);
    for i=1:l
        if(mod(i-1,2) == 0)
            d = v(i) * 2.;
            sum_ = sum_ + floor( double(d) / 10.0);
            sum_ = sum_ + mod(d, 10);
        else
            sum_ = sum_ + v(i);
        end
    end
    checkValue = mod((10 - mod(sum_, 10)),10);

    % Check Computed value with last digit
    isISIN = int8(str2double(Isin(end))) == checkValue;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach in Swift.

It checks first for the requirement 2 letters + 10 alphanumeric characters with Regular Expression

```
func validateISIN(_ isin : String) -> Bool {
    guard isin.range(of: "^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]{10}$", options: .regularExpression) != nil,
        let checksum = Int(isin.suffix(1)) else { return false }
    let digits = isin.dropLast().map{Int(String($0), radix: 36)!}.map(String.init).joined()
    var sum = 0
    var evenFlag = true
    digits.reversed().forEach { character in
        var integer = Int(String(character))!
        if evenFlag { integer *= 2 }
        sum += integer / 10
        sum += integer % 10
        evenFlag.toggle()
    }
    return (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10 == checksum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin version to validate checksum:

```kotlin
fun check(isin: String): Boolean {
    val isinInts = isin.map { it.toString().toInt(36) }
        .joinToString("").map { Character.getNumericValue(it) }
    val multipliers = isinInts.indices.map { it % 2 + 1 }.reversed()
    val sum = multipliers.indices.sumOf { index: Int ->
        (isinInts[index] * multipliers[index]).let { it / 10 + it % 10 }
    }
    return (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10 == 0
}
```