# Replace accented characters in R with non-accented counterpart (UTF-8 encoding)

Tags: r, non-ascii-characters

I have some strings in R in UTF-8 encoding that contain accents.
E.g.
`string="Hølmer"` or `string="Elizalde-González"`

Is there any nice function in R to replace the accented characters in these strings by their unaccented counterpart? I saw some solutions in PHP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php/3373364#3373364), but how do I do this in R?

E.g. the PHP code

```
$unwanted_array = array(    'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
                            'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
                            'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
                            'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
                            'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );
$str = strtr( $str, $unwanted_array );
```

seemed quite nice - but how would I do this in R?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The below answers are basically taken from elsewhere. The key is getting your `unwanted_array` in the right format. You might want it as a `list`:

```
unwanted_array = list(    'Š'='S', 'š'='s', 'Ž'='Z', 'ž'='z', 'À'='A', 'Á'='A', 'Â'='A', 'Ã'='A', 'Ä'='A', 'Å'='A', 'Æ'='A', 'Ç'='C', 'È'='E', 'É'='E',
                            'Ê'='E', 'Ë'='E', 'Ì'='I', 'Í'='I', 'Î'='I', 'Ï'='I', 'Ñ'='N', 'Ò'='O', 'Ó'='O', 'Ô'='O', 'Õ'='O', 'Ö'='O', 'Ø'='O', 'Ù'='U',
                            'Ú'='U', 'Û'='U', 'Ü'='U', 'Ý'='Y', 'Þ'='B', 'ß'='Ss', 'à'='a', 'á'='a', 'â'='a', 'ã'='a', 'ä'='a', 'å'='a', 'æ'='a', 'ç'='c',
                            'è'='e', 'é'='e', 'ê'='e', 'ë'='e', 'ì'='i', 'í'='i', 'î'='i', 'ï'='i', 'ð'='o', 'ñ'='n', 'ò'='o', 'ó'='o', 'ô'='o', 'õ'='o',
                            'ö'='o', 'ø'='o', 'ù'='u', 'ú'='u', 'û'='u', 'ý'='y', 'ý'='y', 'þ'='b', 'ÿ'='y' )
```

You can do this easily with `iconv` or `chartr`:

```
> iconv(string, to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')
[1] "Holmer"

> chartr(paste(names(unwanted_array), collapse=''),
         paste(unwanted_array, collapse=''),
         string)
[1] "Holmer"
```

Otherwise you have to loop through all of replacements because `mapply` or similar wouldn't account for symbols already replaced by previous `gsub` operations.:

```
# the loop:
out <- string
for(i in seq_along(unwanted_array))
    out <- gsub(names(unwanted_array)[i],unwanted_array[i],out)
```

The result:

```
> out
[1] "Holmer"
```

Comment: Ha many thanks! I hadn't seen the other threads - sorry for that... iconv(string from="UTF-8",to="ASCII//TRANSLIT") did the trick for me! Thanks so much!

Comment: Note:  unwanted_array above is missing 'ü'='u'.

Comment: Hi, this solution has been working fine for me for quite some time, but now it just stopped working, and I don't know why. I created a function called "cleanWord.r" where I included @Thomas function. I used to call it like: cleanWord("ááb") and the result was "aab". Now, I'm getting an error saying that chartr's argument "old" is longer than "new". I printed both of these arguments from the chartr function, and they are indeed different. The "new" argument is fine, but the "old" has some encoding problems. For instance, it starts like this: "Ã€Ã\u0081". Any ideas on how to fix this? Tnks a lot

Comment: The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38171652/3277050) on the linked question that uses stringi worked great for me and will be better for tidyverse folks since you probably already have the packge

Comment: I agree with see24, `stringi::stri_trans_general(string, "Latin-ASCII")` works much better!

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/issues/149#issuecomment-289151373

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use `gsubfn` package:

```
library(gsubfn)
string="Hølmer"
gsubfn(paste(names(unwanted_array),collapse='|'), unwanted_array,string)
[1] "Holmer"
```

Comment: Some performance issues with this solution