# Encoding problem when calling function in r

Tags: r, function, encoding

I need a function in R to "clean" accents from a string. I was using the accepted solution from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20495866/7396118

I created an external function, included the algorithm proposed by @Thomas, and saved in a function clean.r. So when i called clean("ááb"), the result was "aab".

This worked just fine for a long time, but now, all of a sudden, it stoped working. When I try to call the function, I get the following message: Error in chartr(old, new, x) : 'old' is longer than 'new'.

When I print each argument from inside my "clean.r" function, they look like:

print(old) > "Ã€Ã\u0081Ã‚ÃƒÃ ..."

print(new) >  "AAAAA..."

So, they are indeed different. When I call the function, it does not understand the correct encoding for the characters with accent. When I open the clean.r file and run the code line by line, it works fine, but when I call it from within another function, it doesn't work. I'm importing it as source("clean.r")

Does anyone know how can I deal with that? Is there a simpler way to exclude accents from a string?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `textclean::replace_non_ascii("ááb")`