# Character replacement with gsub not working inside a function

Tags: r, gsub

I'm trying to replace some unexpected characters in a data frame in R. According to [Replace multiple arguments with gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253954/replace-multiple-arguments-with-gsub), gsub function is supposed to work properly in this cases, so I tried that way.

The values I have in the first column of the data frame are the following:

```
La FlÃ¨che Wallonne
LiÃ¨ge - Bastogne - LiÃ¨ge
Tour de Romandie
Giro dÂ´Italia
CritÃ©rium du DauphinÃ©
```

And the code's been implemented as follows:

```
callChangeCharacters <- function(results){
for(i in 1:nrow(results)){
    race <- results[i,1]
    race <- gsub("Ã©","e",race)
    race <- gsub("Ã¢","a",race)
    race <- gsub("Ã³","o",race)
    race <- gsub("Å¾","z",race)
    race <- gsub("Ãº","u",race)
    race <- gsub("Ã¸","o",race)
    race <- gsub("Å›","s",race)
    race <- gsub("Å‚","l",race)
    race <- gsub("Ã¤‚","a",race)
    race <- gsub("Ã¨","e",race)
    race <- gsub("Ã","a",race)
    race <- gsub("Å","s",race)
    race <- gsub("Ä","c",race)
    race <- gsub("Â´","'",race)
    results[i,1] <- race
}
return(results)
}
```

If I run the code which is inside the for loop, I success to get the expected result:

```
La Fleche Wallonne
Liege - Bastogne - Liege
Tour de Romandie
Giro d'Italia
Criterium du Dauphine
```

However, if I call the function, the result isn't the same, and the unwanted characters aren't corrected:

```
> correctedDF <- callChangeCharacters(results)
> correctedDF
                                        V1
La FlÃ¨che Wallonne
LiÃ¨ge - Bastogne - LiÃ¨ge
Tour de Romandie
Giro dÂ´Italia
CritÃ©rium du DauphinÃ©
```

The output of the result I get is the following (this version of results is longer but the problem is the same):

```
> dput(results)
structure(list(V1 = c("Santos Tour Down Under", "Paris - Nice", 
"Tirreno-Adriatico", "Milano-Sanremo", "Volta Ciclista a Catalunya", 
"E3 Prijs Vlaanderen - Harelbeke", "Gent - Wevelgem", "Ronde van Vlaanderen / Tour des Flandres", 
"Vuelta Ciclista al Pais Vasco", "Paris - Roubaix", "Amstel Gold Race", 
"La FlÃ¨che Wallonne", "LiÃ¨ge - Bastogne - LiÃ¨ge", "Tour de Romandie", 
"Giro dÂ´Italia", "CritÃ©rium du DauphinÃ©", "Tour de Suisse", 
"Tour de France", "Tour de Pologne", NA, "Clasica Ciclista San Sebastian", 
"Eneco Tour", "Vuelta a EspaÃ±a", "Vattenfall Cyclassics", "GP Ouest France - Plouay", 
"Grand Prix Cycliste de QuÃ©bec", "Grand Prix Cycliste de MontrÃ©al", 
"Il Lombardia", "Tour of Beijing")), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(1L, 
1686L, 4601L, 6743L, 6943L, 9274L, 9473L, 9673L, 9880L, 11581L, 
11779L, 11978L, 12168L, 12367L, 14264L, 21957L, 24734L, 27727L, 
35542L, 37354L, 37470L, 37627L, 39885L, 47277L, 47441L, 47624L, 
47788L, 47952L, 48147L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any idea of why it doesn't work inside the function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure of the answer, sorry, but I got your code to work just fine, assuming your original data frame is named "results" and it's a character column. Have you tried restarting R? I've had similar issues where `grep` functions won't work.

Comment: your function works fine for me. can you write the output of `dput(results)` in your question.

Comment: Thanks @Branden, but got the same result: it worked running the for loop, but didn't correct the wrong characters while executing the function.

Comment: @DhawalKapil, actually the output I'm getting is written in the question, at least if I understand what you are asking for.

Comment: i want you to write the `results` object that you are passing to the function.
you can write it using `dput(results)`

Comment: Ok @DhawalKapil, I've just added the output in the final part of the question.

Comment: That indicates your input is a vector, not a data frame. I don't know how you got the for loop to work because `nrow(results)` when `results` is a vector returns `NULL` and `results[1,1]` returns an error. Try changing `results` to a data frame or, alternatively, using `NROW` (or `length`) instead of `nrow` and replacing `results[i,1]` with `results[i]` in the function.

Comment: That's true @Branden, I mixed elements when restarted R. Now I have tried with a data frame (I'm going to edit again that part of the question), and the result is the same. I'll try your alternatives anyway.

Comment: I recreated the data frame using your `dput` output and the function worked as desired. Maybe try it on another machine or on an online interpreter (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/r_terminal_online.php). If your code works on either of those then that indicates it's probably something specific to your machine, and not something wrong with your code.

Comment: @BrandenMurray I tried reinstalling RGui, but it didn't either work. Tomorrow I'll try in another machine, and see if it works there.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, which occurred because I was using the `source` function to import my code without specifying that the `encoding` parameter should be `"utf-8"`.

```
source("./code.R")
```

Upon inspecting a function I had read in, I realised that certain special characters had been changed by the `source` function and hence the function was not working as intended. The solution was to set the `encoding` parameter to `"utf-8"`.

```
source("./code.R", encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. Also, you should also change `Ã±` (see "Vuelta a EspaÃ±a").

The `gsub` function is vectorized so you don't need the loop at all.

```
cleanup <- function(race) {
    race <- gsub("Ã©","e",race)
    race <- gsub("Ã¢","a",race)
    race <- gsub("Ã³","o",race)
    race <- gsub("Å¾","z",race)
    race <- gsub("Ãº","u",race)
    race <- gsub("Ã¸","o",race)
    race <- gsub("Å›","s",race)
    race <- gsub("Å‚","l",race)
    race <- gsub("Ã¤‚","a",race)
    race <- gsub("Ã¨","e",race)
    race <- gsub("Ã","a",race)
    race <- gsub("Å","s",race)
    race <- gsub("Ä","c",race)
    race <- gsub("Â´","'",race)
    return(race)
}

results$V1 <- cleanup(results$V1)
```

Why do you use a data.frame if you only have one column? It would be more convenient to just keep a vector `race`.

If you really want a function which works on `results` directly, still no loop.

```
callChangeCharacters <- function(results) {
    results[,1] <- cleanup(results[,1])
    return(results)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fixes. This way it looks much faster. I was working with data frames because I have more columns with characters to correct, but I can get by with vectors also. Anyway, it'n not working yet. I'll try in another machine as stated in the previous response.