# How to use gsub function to get rid of all special characters at the start of each record of Address column?

Tags: regex, r, gsub

```
Address <- c("#20 W Irving ST","@1 East Street",
             "%222 Rockfard Avenue","-145 W Locust","& 99 East Locus")
Number <- c("A-1","A-2","A-3","A-4","A-5")
DF <- data.frame(Address,Number)
```

Comment: And what have you tried first?

Comment: Is the first element of each string a special character?  If so, perhaps just delete the first element, i.e., delete the first 'space'.

Comment: @MarkMiller the data set has around 70,000 records and I need to match the address column for destination and origin, but the data has some bad entries like the one I mentioned above which starts with special character, so I was trying to get rid of special characters only which are present at the start of address.

Comment: Are you saying some of the addresses have a special character at the beginning and some of the addresses do not?

Comment: `gsub("^[[:punct:][:space:]]+","",DF$Address)`

Comment: @MarkMillerYes, that's right.

Comment: @thelatemail I'll try that, Thanks!

Comment: @thelatemail It worked, Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Just remove any repeated punctuation or space characters immediately following the start of the string. In regex speak:

```
gsub("^[[:punct:][:space:]]+","",DF$Address)
#[1] "20 W Irving ST"      "1 East Street"       "222 Rockfard Avenue" "145 W Locust"       
#[5] "99 East Locus"
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this do what you want?  This assumes the first element of every `Address` is a special character.  Note also that for this code to work, the left-hand end of `my.data$Address` must be flush with the left edge of the R GUI.  There cannot be any empty characters at the start of `Address`.

```
my.data <- read.csv(text = '

        Address,        Number
#20 W Irving ST,         A-1
@1 East Street,          A-2
%222 Rockfard Avenue,    A-3
-145 W Locust,           A-4
& 99 East Locus,         A-5

', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.string = 'NA')

my.data

my.data$Address <- substr(my.data$Address, 2, nchar(my.data$Address))
my.data
```

If the special characters can occur anywhere in `Address` and you want to remove all of the special characters you can try one of the functions presented here:

[Replace multiple arguments with gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253954/replace-multiple-arguments-with-gsub)

I used the function written by Theodore Lytras with this line:

```
mgsub(c('#','@','%','-','&'), c('','','','',''), my.data$Address)
```

Note that with both approaches the address `99 East Locus` now begins with an empty space.

If some of the addresses have a special character in their first element and some of the addresses do not, this might work:

```
my.data <- read.csv(text = '

        Address,        Number
#20 W Irving ST,         A-1
@1 East Street,          A-2
222 W Locust,            A-4
%222 Rockfard Avenue,    A-3
-145 W Locust,           A-4
5 East Street,           A-2
& 99 East Locus,         A-5

', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.string = 'NA')

first.char <- substr(my.data$Address, 1, 1)

my.data$Address <- ifelse(first.char %in% c('#','@','%','-','&'), substr(my.data$Address, 2, nchar(my.data$Address)), my.data$Address)
my.data
```

Comment: Miler I tried but it is having the same output as input, its not getting rid of the special characters

Comment: All of the examples I presented are working on my computer.  I do not know what the problem is.  Perhaps put your code in your post and I can take a look.

Comment: @ Mark Miler, It worked! I made a mistake. Thank you so much!