# grepl in R to find matches to any of a list of character strings

Tags: r, regex, grepl

Is it possible to use a *grepl* argument when referring to a list of values, maybe using the %in% operator? I want to take the data below and if the animal name has "dog" or "cat" in it, I want to return a certain value, say, "keep"; if it doesn't have "dog" or "cat", I want to return "discard".

```
data <- data.frame(animal = sample(c("cat","dog","bird", 'doggy','kittycat'), 50, replace = T))
```

Now, if I were just to do this by strictly matching values, say, "cat" and "dog', I could use the following approach:

```
matches <- c("cat","dog")

data$keep <- ifelse(data$animal %in% matches, "Keep", "Discard")
```

But using grep or grepl only refers to the first argument in the list:

```
data$keep <- ifelse(grepl(matches, data$animal), "Keep","Discard")
```

returns

```
Warning message:
In grepl(matches, data$animal) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Note, I saw this thread in my search, but this doesn't appear to work:
[grep using a character vector with multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-in-r-with-a-list-of-patterns)

Comment: I thought Brian Diggs answer to the link question provided the needed code if you left off the `unique`. It's essentially the same as beginneR's answer.

Comment: When you use a function like `sample` without a `set.seed`, it is not considered a reproducible example

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use an "or" (`|`) statement inside the regular expression of `grepl`.

```
ifelse(grepl("dog|cat", data$animal), "keep", "discard")
# [1] "keep"    "keep"    "discard" "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "discard"
# [9] "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "discard" "keep"   
#[17] "discard" "keep"    "keep"    "discard" "keep"    "keep"    "discard" "keep"   
#[25] "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"   
#[33] "keep"    "discard" "keep"    "discard" "keep"    "discard" "keep"    "keep"   
#[41] "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"    "keep"   
#[49] "keep"    "discard"
```

The regular expression `dog|cat` tells the regular expression engine to look for either `"dog"` or `"cat"`, and return the matches for both.

Answer (score 28):

Not sure what you tried but this seems to work:

```
data$keep <- ifelse(grepl(paste(matches, collapse = "|"), data$animal), "Keep","Discard")
```

Similar to the answer you linked to.

The trick is using the paste:

```
paste(matches, collapse = "|")
#[1] "cat|dog"
```

So it creates a regular expression with either dog OR cat and would also work with a long list of patterns without typing each.

#### Edit:

In case you are doing this to later on subset the data.frame according to "Keep" and "Discard" entries, you could do this more directly using:

```
data[grepl(paste(matches, collapse = "|"), data$animal),]
```

This way, the results of `grepl` which are TRUE or FALSE are used for the subset.

Comment: Thanks for using the results as indices, solved a long running annoyance of mine!

Answer (score 16):

Try to avoid `ifelse` as much as possible. This, for example, works nicely

```
c("Discard", "Keep")[grepl("(dog|cat)", data$animal) + 1]
```

For a `123` seed you will get

```
##  [1] "Keep"    "Keep"    "Discard" "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"    "Discard" "Keep"   
##  [9] "Discard" "Discard" "Keep"    "Discard" "Keep"    "Discard" "Keep"    "Keep"   
## [17] "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"   
## [25] "Keep"    "Keep"    "Discard" "Discard" "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"   
## [33] "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"    "Discard" "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"   
## [41] "Keep"    "Discard" "Discard" "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"    "Keep"    "Discard"
## [49] "Keep"    "Keep"
```

Comment: set.seed(123) to seed the random generator.

Comment: @RichardScriven, because the OP provided his data set using `sample`, thus I can't provide an output that he can validate without setting a seed

Comment: @DavidArenburg, why try to avoid "ifelse"?

Comment: @MarcTulla, because `ifelse` (although being vectorized) is relatively slow, especially in cases when you embed several `ifelse` statements. Thus, if I can easily avoid it, I prefer the do so. Although I guess it is a personal choice

Comment: @DavidArenburg, that makes sense, and I have noticed it slowing things down, especially on big datasets. If I do need to do an "ifelse"-type operation, is the preferred approach beginneR's below? Something like: data[grepl(paste(matches, collapse = "|"), data$animal),]

Comment: @MarcTulla, beginneR solution is the best option if you need to subset the data. If you just need to create a `"Discard", "Keep"` vector, I would go with mine :)

Comment: Makes sense -- I ultimately want to use this vector to subset (though that's beyond the scope of the original question)

Comment: Two years later and now I would totally recommend this over anything else.

Comment: @DavidArenburg My context is to match col_1 against pattern. If matched, then 'text', if not then col_1. Am I able to get away without using ifelse?

Comment: @DavidArenburg In response to my previous question:
df[ grepl(pattern, col_1, perl = T), col_1 := 'text']