# R: filtering by list(s) of strings and returning all results that start with the content of the lists

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, filter, dplyr

I have a very large data frame containing diagnoses and I need find matches for let's say: 
    `AMI  <- c("DI21", "410")`
or
    `STROKE <- c("DI63", "DI64", "DI60", "DI61")`

```
DB <- data.frame(c("I21", "I210", "D21", "D210")) 
DB$DIAGNOSECOL2 <- c("E21", "E210", "I21", "I211")
names(DB)[1] <- "DIAGNOSECOL1"
```

I can do this using

```
library(dplyr)
FILTEREDDB <- dplyr::filter(DB, DATABASE$DIAGNOSECOL1 %in% AMI |
DB$DIAGNOSECOL1 %in% STROKE | DB$DIAGNOSECOL2 %in% AMI | DB$DIAGNOSECOL2 %in% STROKE)
```

This works fine, but the problem is I get to few results, because some diagnoses contains subcodings i.e. "DI210" or "DI211". So I want to filter through values that contains or begins with (either way) the values in the lists AMI or STROKE.

For me it seems a solution would be using grepl() i.e.

```
grepl(AMI, DB)
```

however I get the warning "argument 'pattern' has length >1 and only the first argument will be used." 
(grepl() inserts my list as - a list, and just takes the first argument)

The best solution to this I could find was this: [grepl in R to find matches to any of a list of character strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391975/grepl-in-r-to-find-matches-to-any-of-a-list-of-character-strings)
So I reluctantly tried to skip the lists and directly insert my values to get on with my life:

```
dplyr::filter(DB, grepl(c("DI21", "410"), DB$DIAGNOSECOL1 | DB$DIAGNOSECOL2)
```

This didn't work however - I get a long list of different warnings, so maybe grel() isn't the way to go when I have to check in several columns? I tried a bunch of other stuff, that didn't work either. I think it's really surprising that I can't find an answer to this, because it seems pretty basic to me.

If you can recommend a nice way to adresse this problem, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: grepl works within dplyr::filter. Just use either subsetting (i.e. AMI[[1]]) for individual values or paste(AMI, collapse = "|") to search for multiple). I would also reformat the DB from wide to long.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you want in output. I assume you want to filter rows that contains a pattern in AMI or STROKE without taking into account the "D".

The solution uses regex quantifier "?" to ignore D:

```
STROKE_regex <- sub(x = STROKE, pattern = "D", replacement = "D?")
AMI_regex <- sub(x = AMI, pattern = "D", replacement = "D?")


filter_at(DB, vars(contains("DIAGNOSECOL")),
        any_vars(grepl(x = ., pattern = paste(c(AMI_regex, STROKE_regex), collapse = "|"))))
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want. Thank you!
I'm not entirely sure why though. If I had the AMI and STROKE defined using the ? (i.e. "D?I63") then I could leave out the _regex step and just
    filter_at(DB, vars(contains("DIAGNOSECOL")),
        any_vars(grepl(x = ., pattern = paste(c(AMI, STROKE), collapse = "|")))) right?

Comment: With "DI63" : only "DI63" can be matched.
With "D?I63": both "DI63" and "I63" can be matched.