# grepl for finding words

Tags: r, regex, grepl, multiple-matches

I am trying in R to find the spanish words in a number of words. I have all the spanish words from a excel that I don´t know how to attach in the post (it has more than 80000 words), and I am trying to check if some words are on it, or not.

For example:

```
words = c("Silla", "Sillas", "Perro", "asdfg")
```

I tried to use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391975/grepl-in-r-to-find-matches-to-any-of-a-list-of-character-strings):

```
grepl(paste(spanish_words, collapse = "|"), words)
```

But there is too much spanish words, and gives me this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uRO4.png)

So... who can i do it? I also tried this:

```
toupper(words) %in% toupper(spanish_words)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2JvQ.png)

As you can see with this option only gives TRUE in exactly matches, and I need that "Sillas" also appear as TRUE (it is the plural word of silla). That was the reason that I tried first with grepl, for get plurals aswell.

Any idea?

Comment: I don't think regex/grepl is the solution here, maybe use dedicated packages, `tm` package comes to mind, there might be more specialised dictionary style packages, too.

Comment: The error thrown by `grepl` is not because you have too many words in your pattern but because your regex is not valid.

Comment: You need to put your regex in parentheses. You have `word|word2|word3...` but you should have `(word|word2|word3...)`.

Answer (score 1):

As df:

```
df <- tibble(text = c("some words", 
                      "more words", 
                      "Perro", 
                      "And asdfg", 
                      "Comb perro and asdfg"))
```

Vector of words: 
    words <- c("Silla", "Sillas", "Perro", "asdfg")
    words <- tolower(paste(words, collapse = "|"))

Then use `mutate` and `str_detect`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
   text = tolower(text), 
   spanish_word = str_detect(text, words)
 )
```

Returns:

```
text                 spanish_word
  <chr>                <lgl>       
1 some words           FALSE       
2 more words           FALSE       
3 perro                TRUE        
4 and asdfg            TRUE        
5 comb perro and asdfg TRUE
```