# Loop 2 dataframes to identify common strings in columns with grepl

Tags: r

**Reproducible Example**

***Table1***

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c('hisas', 'myjafs', 'namegaefi'))
       Name
1     hisas
2    myjafs
3 namegaefi
```

***Table2***

```
ref <- data.frame(Name = c('john', 'hello', 'his', 'name', 'random'))

    Name
1   john
2  hello
3    his
4   name
5 random
```

**Expected Output**

```
       Name   Test
1     hisas    T
2    myjafs    F
3 namegaefi    T
```

**Question**

I'm trying to use grepl to see if the string in table 2 can be found in table 1, and conditionally update a new column i. Test to reflect *T* or *F*

> Failed Code

```
grepl(df$Name,ref$Name,  fixed=TRUE)
```

Comment: Relevant [grepl in R to find matches to any of a list of character strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391975/grepl-in-r-to-find-matches-to-any-of-a-list-of-character-strings)

Comment: `df$Test <- grepl(paste0(ref$Name, collapse = "|"), df$Name)`

Comment: ah i forgot abt the paste0 with pipe operator. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c('hisas', 'myjafs', 'namegaefi'))
ref <- data.frame(Name = c('john', 'hello', 'his', 'name', 'random'))
sapply(df$Name, function(s) any(sapply(ref$Name, grepl,  x=s, fixed=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun a solution using `adist`. Of course, this won't scale well.

```
d <- adist(df$Name, ref$Name, costs = list(insertions = 1, deletions = 0, substitutions = 1))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    3    4    0    3    5
#[2,]    3    5    2    3    5
#[3,]    3    4    2    0    4

rowSums(!d) > 0
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You could `paste` the `ref$Name` together as one pattern and then use `grepl`

```
df$Test <- grepl(paste0(ref$Name, collapse = "|"), df$Name)

df
#       Name  Test
#1     hisas  TRUE
#2    myjafs FALSE
#3 namegaefi  TRUE
```