# get rows of where the column has either one or both of the strings in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, row

I have a column that has a list of items like this

```
Fruit
Apple
Apple, Orange
Kiwi, Orange, Apple 
Kiwi
```

I want to get the rows that contain (Apple, Orange). I'm not sure how to do it, I've tried `str_detect` and `filter` but none has worked so far to any other advice would be appreciated.

Comment: extension to this question. Lets say im getting the rows of apple and orange, but its also giving me the rows of pineapple since apple is in that word as well. how do I prevent this?

Comment: You can do that with the `grepl()` answer (bellow) with a explicit regex. 

You can add in front of the regex expression `(\\s|^)`. `\\s` is the space (" ") character and and `^` represents the start of the string. So by writing `(\\s|^)([Aa]pple|[Oo]range)` you select every string containing "apple" or "orange" that have a space before the word or that is in the bigining of the string (sentence). 

Finally you can write `df[grepl("(\\s|^)([Aa]pple|[Oo]range)", df$fruits),, drop=FALSE]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% filter(str_detect(Fruit, 'Apple|Orange'))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  Fruit              
  <chr>              
1 Apple              
2 Apple, Orange      
3 Kiwi, Orange, Apple
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  Fruit              
  <chr>              
1 Apple              
2 Apple, Orange      
3 Kiwi, Orange, Apple
4 Kiwi
```

Comment: this works but what if I also wanted to print out row 3 since it does contain the words apple and orange

Comment: @user14262341, have updated my answer, please check if it works for you.

Comment: ah yes but you are also missing apple, so rows 1 through 3 should show up

Comment: @user14262341, so you need rows that either contain Apple or Orange or Both? Have updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: You can write `df %>% filter(str_detect(Fruit, "(\\s|^)([Aa]pple|[Oo]range)"))` which does the trick. See comment to your question above

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like using `grepl()` for those kind of problems. You can play around the regex to select rows. (See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391975/grepl-in-r-to-find-matches-to-any-of-a-list-of-character-strings))

```
df <- data.frame(list("fruits" = c("Apple", "Apple, Orange", "Kiwi, Apple", "Kiwi")))
```

Visualization of df:

```
| id | fruits        | 
|----|---------------|
| 1  | Apple         | 
| 2  | Apple, Orange |
| 3  | Kiwi, Apple   |
| 3  | Kiwi          |
```

Then you can write:

```
df_only_apples <- df[grepl("[Aa]pple", df$fruits),, drop=FALSE]
```

which will give you

```
| id | fruits        | 
|----|---------------|
| 1  | Apple         | 
| 2  | Apple, Orange |
| 3  | Kiwi, Apple   |
```

But if you want to select rows that contain "Apples" and "Oranges" you could just write `df[grepl("([Aa]pple|[Oo]range)", df$fruits)`

Comment: yeah for some reason this doesnt work if the order isn't the same? like if it had been orange, kiwi, apple this does not work

Comment: The order of the words in a sentence should not affect the results from grepl(). I also tested the regex `([Aa]pple|[Oo]range)` which works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

We can also split the column and use `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    separate_rows(fruits) %>%
    group_by(rn) %>% 
    filter(any(c('Apple', 'Orange') %in% fruits)) %>% 
    summarise(fruits = toString(fruits), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    select(-rn)
```