# R: Why can't for loop or c() work out for grep function?

Tags: r

Thanks for [grep using a character vector with multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-in-r-with-a-list-of-patterns), I figured out my own problem as well.
The question here was how to find multiple values by using grep function,
and the solution was either these:

```
grep("A1| A9 | A6")
```

or

```
toMatch <- c("A1", "A9", "A6")
matches <- unique (grep(paste(toMatch,collapse="|")
```

So I used the second suggestion since I had MANY values to search for.

But I'm curious why c() or for loop doesn't work out instead of |.
Before I researched the possible solution in stackoverflow and found recommendations above, I tried out two alternatives that I'll demonstrate below:

First, what I've written in R was something like this:

```
find.explore.l<-lapply(text.words.bl ,function(m) grep("^explor",m))
```

But then I had to 'grep' many words, so I tried out this

```
find.explore.l<-lapply(text.words.bl ,function(m) grep(c("A1","A2","A3"),m))
```

It didn't work, so I tried another one(XXX is the list of words that I'm supposed to find in the text)

```
for (i in XXX){
  find.explore.l<-lapply(text.words.bl ,function(m) grep("XXX[i]"),m))
    .......(more lines to append lines etc)
   }
```

and it seemed like R tried to match XXX[i] itself, not the words inside.
Why can't c() and for loop for grep return right results?
Someone please let me know! I'm so curious :P

Comment: `grep(c("A1","A2","A3"),m))` doesn't work because `grep` is not vectorized over the `pattern` argument - it has to be a single regular expression. `grep("XXX[i]"),m))` doesn't work because you have quotes around `XXX[i]`, so it's interpreted as a string literal rather than evaluated as an object.

Comment: Can you show some input and output? Have you considered the `Vectorize` function?

Comment: `grep(c("A1","A2","A3"),m))` is violating the grep syntax. `grep(pattern, x,...`. Pattern is required to be a single string, you supplied a vector of three character strings. Another way to put it is `length(pattern)` should be `1`. Also, `function(m) grep("XXX[i]"),m))` has a misplaced closed paranthesis after `"XXX[i]"`. Again check the documentation for grep and its examples.

Comment: Hi, it shoud be ‘’’grep("A1|A9|A6") ‘’’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for the `pattern=` argument in the `grep()` function:

> Character string containing a regular expression (or character string for `fixed = TRUE`) to be matched in the given character vector. Coerced by `as.character` to a character string if possible. **If a character vector of length 2 or more is supplied, the first element is used with a warning**. Missing values are allowed except for `regexpr` and `gregexpr`.

This confirms that, as @nrussell said in a comment, `grep()` is not vectorized over the pattern argument. Because of this, `c()` won't work for a list of regular expressions.

You *could*, however, use a loop, you just have to modify your syntax.

```
toMatch <- c("A1", "A9", "A6")

# Loop over values to match
for (i in toMatch) {
    grep(i, text)
}
```

Using `"XXX[i]"` as your pattern doesn't work because it's interpreting that as a regular expression. That is, it will match exactly `XXXi`. To reference an element of a vector of regular expressions, you would simply use `XXX[i]` (note the lack of surrounding quotes).

You can `apply()` this, but in a slightly different way than you had done. You apply it to each *regex* in the list, rather than each text string.

```
lapply(toMatch, function(rgx, text) grep(rgx, text), text = text)
```

However, the best approach would be, as you already have in your post, to use

```
matches <- unique(grep(paste(toMatch, collapse = "|"), text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that:

```
XXX <- c("a", "b", "XXX[i]")
grep("XXX[i]", XXX, value=T)
character(0)
grep("XXX\\[i\\]", XXX, value=T)
[1] "XXX[i]"
```

What is R doing? It is using special rules for the first argument of `grep`. The brackets are considered special characters (`[` and `]`). I put in two backslashes to tell R to consider them regular brackets. And imgaine what would happen if I put that last expression into a `for` loop? It wouldn't do what I expected.

If you would like a `for` loop that goes through a character vector of possible matches, take out the quotes in the `grep` function.

```
#if you want the match returned
matches <- c("a", "b")
for (i in matches) print(grep(i, XXX, value=T))
[1] "a"
[1] "b"

#if you want the vector location of the match
for (i in matches) print(grep(i, XXX))
[1] 1
[1] 2
```

As the comments point out, `grep(c("A1","A2","A3"),m))` is violating the `grep` required syntax.