# Installing packages that have a common string in a loop

Tags: r, installation, package, install.packages

I've recently came across [Deducer](http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/index.php?n=Main.PlotBuilder), it crossed my mind to have a look at it and I progressed to installing the package. After searching through CRAN it occurred to me that there is a number of packages that support *Deducer*:

[image: packs]

Instead of running:

```
install.packages("Deducer")
install.packages("DeducerExtras")
```

I would prefer to run a loop for all the packages that have *Deducer* string in the name. Hence my question, *how can I get list of packages from CRAN where name matches specific string and install them in a loop?*

Comment: `install.packages(grep("Deducer",available.packages()[,1],value = TRUE))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite raw:

```
out <- available.packages()
libs <- as.vector(out[grep("Deducer", out[,1]),1])
lapply(libs, install.packages)
```

Comment: If someone has some idea for improvement, please feel free to edit.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is neat solution. I'm guessing that it would be also useful to run a `grep` with [a list of patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7664655/1655567) so the one could install a number of related packages in the same time, like `grid` and `ggplpot` as well as `ggthemes`.