# Filter a column which contains several keywords

Tags: r

I am trying to filter a column which contains several keywords (in this example dog and cat) but I am having problems as only the first element is being used.

```
id <- c(1:7)
type <- c("dog1","dog2" ,"cat1","cat2","zebra1", "parrot5", "elephant15")
filter1 <- c("dog","cat")
df1 <- data.frame(id,type)
dfilter <- df1[grep(filter1,df1$type),]
dfilter
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` can use `|` as an or, so why not paste your filters together with `|` as a separator:

```
dfilter <- df1[grep(paste0(filter1, collapse = "|"), df1$type),]
```

Comment: wonder how many more variations of your answer will be posted

Comment: @rawr What about passing `df1[["type"]]` to `grep`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dfilter <- df1[sapply(filter1, function(x) grep(x,df1$type)),]
```

It's complaining because your filter is a vector and grep wants a string.

### Edit:

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-in-r-with-a-list-of-patterns):

```
dfilter <- df1[df1$type %in% grep(paste(filter1, collapse="|"), df1$type, value=TRUE), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @Tgsmith61591 mentioned, the pattern argument for the grep function requires a string. Since you're passing in a vector it's warning you that it will only process the first element.

Another solution would be something like this:

```
dfilter <- unique(grep(paste(filter1, collapse = "|"), df1$type, value=TRUE))
```

See this post [grep using a character vector with multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-in-r-with-a-list-of-patterns)

Answer (score 1):

```
df1[(gsub('\\d','',df1$type) %in% filter1),]
  id type
1  1 dog1
2  2 dog2
3  3 cat1
4  4 cat2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dplyr method:

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

data = data_frame(
  id = c(1:7),
  type = c("dog1","dog2" ,"cat1","cat2","zebra1", "parrot5", "elephant15")
)


data %>%
  filter(animals %>%
           paste(collapse = "|") %>%
           stri_detect_regex(type, . ) )
```