# R grep with 'AND' logic

Tags: r

I'm working with `RJDBC` on a server whose maintainers frequently update jar versions. Since `RJDBC` requires classpaths, this poses a problem when paths break. My situation is fortuitous in that the most current jars will always be in the same directory, but the version numbers will have changed.

I'm trying to use a simple `grep` function in R to isolate which jar I need based on a regex with some `AND` logic, however R makes this surprisingly difficult...

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-in-r-with-a-list-of-patterns) demonstrates how `grep` in R can function with the `|` operator for OR logic, but I can't seem to find similar AND logic operator.

Here's an example:

```
## Let's say I have three jars in a directory
jars <- list.files('/the/dir')
> jars
[1] "hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.4.3-standalone.jar" "hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.4.3.jar" "jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar"
```

The jar I want is "hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.4.3-standalone.jar"—how can I use AND logic in grep to extract it?

```
## I know that OR logic is supported:
j <- jars[grep('hive-jdbc|standalone', jars)]
> j
[1] "hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.4.3-standalone.jar" "hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.4.3.jar" "jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar"

## Would AND logic look like the same format?
> jars[grep('hive-jdbc&standalone', jars)]
character(0)
```

Not all-that-surprisingly, that last piece doesn't work... I found a [useful, yet non-comprehensive, link](https://stat545-ubc.github.io/block022_regular-expression.html) for grep in R, but it doesn't show an AND operator. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
grep('hive-jdbc.*standalone', jars) # 'hive-jdbc' followed by 'standalone'
```

or

```
grepl('hive-jdbc', jars) & grepl('standalone', jars) # 'hive-jdbc' AND 'standalone'
```