# Vectorized stringr with fixed (literal) characters

Tags: r, string, stringr, tidyverse

I've got the following code, which I expect to give me a list of 3, since there are 3 elements in `texts`:

```
library(stringr)
texts <- c("I doubt it! :)", ";) disagree, but ok.", "No emoticons here!!!")
smileys <- c(":)","(:",";)",":D")
str_extract_all(texts, fixed(smileys))
```

Instead, I get a list of four (the length of my "pattern" parameter, here the `smileys`.  Additionally, I get the following warning message:

> Warning message: In stri_extract_all_fixed(string, pattern, simplify =
>   simplify,  : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object
>   length```

Well, I don't imagine length *will* match, as I'm looking for *any* hits on *any* of the smileys in each text.  It's not like I want to match string 1 with pattern 1, string 2 with pattern 2, etc.

Aware that I am messing up stringi's understanding of vectorizing, I have tried this instead:

```
texts %>% map(~ str_extract_all(.x, fixed(smileys)))
```

This is much better, as it gives me a list of 3, but each element is in turn a list of four.

What I'm trying to get to is a list of 3 that is as little nested as possible.  Someone, somewhere, has solved this, but I can't for the life of me figure it out or get how to google it.  I could do a for loop over this, but I consider myself a citizen of the tidyverse...

Grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Not familiar with `stringr`, but I believe you may have look at [grep using a character vector with multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-using-a-character-vector-of-patterns). If you pursue the "`paste` `collapse = |`" method, then you might need to consider [How do I deal with special characters like \^$.?*|+()[{ in my regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can try something like this:  `pattern <- paste("\\Q", smileys, "\\E", sep = "", collapse = "|"); stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(texts, pattern)`

Comment: Yeah, the issue of just pasting things together with the pipe is that I'd have to escape out all the parentheses, colons, etc., which make up a lot of the smileys!

Comment: Guilty as charged, @Jota!  I didn't try it before commenting.  Your solution works like a charm!  Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Joy The `Q`/`E` method is described in the second link I provided.

Comment: Thanks, @Henrik!  I jumped to conclusions and assumed you guys didn't realize how important the literal part is.  I'll drink more coffee before commenting next time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `paste` to wrap each element of `smiley` with `\\Q` and `\\E` and collapse on the regex "or" metacharacter (`|`) to form a single pattern. As mentioned in the [link Henrik shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721008/how-do-i-deal-with-special-characters-like-in-my-regex) and documented on [`?regex`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) and in the `stringi` manual, characters between `\\Q` and `\\E` are interpreted literally.

```
pattern <- paste("\\Q", smileys, "\\E", sep = "", collapse = "|")
# [1] "\\Q:)\\E|\\Q(:\\E|\\Q;)\\E|\\Q:D\\E"

library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(texts, pattern)
#[[1]]
#[1] ":)"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] ";)"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] NA
```

Base R:

```
regmatches(texts, gregexpr(pattern, texts))
#[[1]]
#[1] ":)"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] ";)"
#
#[[3]]
#character(0)  
       # If you want an NA, instead of a zero-length vector, 
       # then you could do something like:
       # lapply(
       #   regmatches(texts, gregexpr(pattern, texts)), 
       #   function(ii) ifelse(is.character(ii) & length(ii) == 0L, NA, ii))
```

And if you do want to use `purrr` and avoid regular expressions, one idea would be something like this:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
texts %>% 
  map(~ unlist(str_extract_all(.x, fixed(smileys))))
#[[1]]
#[1] ":)"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] ";)"
#
#[[3]]
#character(0)  
       # if you want NA, not a zero-length vector, you could add:
       # %>% map(~ ifelse(is.character(.x) & length(.x) == 0L, NA, .x))
```