# grepl() - Partial string matching after a symbol

Tags: r, string-matching

I have 2 character vectors:

```
Long <- c("d4@NHL1", "d7@NHL2", "d4@NHL3", "d7@NHL4", "d7@NHL5", "d9@NHL6")
Short <- c("NHL1", "NHL3", "NHL6", "NHL5")
```

I need to check which strings from Long vector partly match strings from Short vector, starting from `@` symbol. I need to get a logic vector as a result.

I think I need to use `grepl()` function, something like this:

```
sapply(Long, function(x) grepl(x, paste(Short, collapse = "")))
```

I don't know what to use as a pattern in `grepl()` function or if there is any argument to start matching after a symbol.

Comment: `grepl(paste(Short, collapse = '|'), Long)` should do it imo

Comment: another option: `gsub('.*@','',Long) %in% Short`

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing the approach from [another stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7664655/1936114):

```
Long <- c("d4@NHL1", "d7@NHL2", "d4@NHL3","d7@NHL4", "d7@NHL5", "d9@NHL6")
Short <- c("NHL1", "NHL3", "NHL6", "NHL5")
matches <- grep(paste0("*@",Short,collapse="|"), 
                Long, value=TRUE)
```

The `*` matches any number of characters before the `@`