# R Select specific files

Tags: r

I want to list all files from my directory that include

```
 20180601    
 20180602
 20180603
 20180604
 20180605
```

that means, all files from these 5 Days. For every day, 24 files exist. Her one example for a file name: 
01-sstessa4de_20180601-030000.tsv

For reading all files from my directory, I applied:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*\\.tsv$")
```

But how can I select data for just 5 days? Is there any solution with

```
grep
```

?

Comment: For this specific case you can use `grepl(paste0('2018060', 1:5, collapse = "|"), temp)` or `grep(paste0('2018060', 1:5, collapse = "|"), temp, value = TRUE)` . You can also create sequence of dates and then `paste` them together.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-using-a-character-vector-with-multiple-patterns

Comment: `pattern="2018060[1-5].*\\.tsv$"`.

Comment: Rui: does not work, it creates an empty character

Comment: Ronak; Think it goes into right direction. But your solution gives my just indices. Please consider,  I want to read this files with read-function later to create a dataframe