# How to extract element from vector that contained substring from another vector in R?

Tags: r

Given:

```
V1 <- c("abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop", "qrst")
V2 <- c("ab", "fg", "op")
```

Is there a R function to get

```
V3 <- string_fxn(V1, V2)
```

Such that

```
V3 = c("abcd", "efgh", "mnop")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep using a character vector with multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-using-a-character-vector-with-multiple-patterns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is `grep` from `base R`

```
grep(paste(V2, collapse="|"), V1, value = TRUE)
#[1] "abcd" "efgh" "mnop"
```

Comment: That accomplishes exactly what I was looking for. Thanks akrun!