# Match vectors by pattern

Tags: r

I have vectors `x` and `type`

```r
x <- c("value", "class", "value2", "value3", "class2", "other")
type <- c("value", "class")
```

and like to match `x` to `type` based on type patterns.
E.g. with `grepl("^value", x)` I get a logical vector of matching patterns for the element "value" in `type`. Using some function of the `apply` family helps to generalize, but how to match this to `x`?

Hope what I'd like to achieve is comprehensible, my desired result in this small example is

```r
c("value", "class", "value", "value", "class")
```

One Note: I prefer a base r solution over tidyverse!

Comment: Related [grep using a character vector with multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-using-a-character-vector-with-multiple-patterns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using nested `sapply`:

```
sapply(x,function(x)type[sapply(type,function(y)grepl(paste0("^",y),x))])
  value   class  value2  value3  class2 
"value" "class" "value" "value" "class"
```

Or if you have unmatched classes:

```
sapply(x,function(x){z <- type[sapply(type,function(y)grepl(paste0("^",y),x))]; ifelse(length(z) > 0, z, NA)})
  value   class  value2  value3  class2   other 
"value" "class" "value" "value" "class"      NA
```

Comment: Could you add `simplify=TRUE` to the outer `sapply`? Otherwise it returns a list in case I have some unmatched type in `x`. I think it then just works

Comment: `simplify = TRUE` is the default. Maybe we can add an `ifelse`

Answer (score 1):

One base R solution using `grep` would be to build a regex alternation using your `type` vector:

```r
regex <- paste0(type, collapse="|")
x[grep(regex, x)]

[1] "value"  "class"  "value2" "value3" "class2"
```

**Data:**

```
x <- c("value", "class", "value2", "value3", "class2", "other")
type <- c("value", "class")
```

Note: I have deliberately added a non matching item `"other"` to the `x` vector to show that `grep` does not pick up on it using your target pattern.

Comment: Works really nice though I'd like to return the matched types, not the values of `x` that can be assigned.