# Matching Wildcard Pattern and Character String in R

Tags: r, wildcard

I am trying to count how many times a keyword appears in a string. In the following variable **text**, I would like to count how many times **keyword** appears in text. The result should display 3 because *AWAY* appears twice and *WIN* appears once in the string.

```
text<- "AWAYTEAM IS XXX. I THINK THEAWAYTEAM WILL WIN"
keyword<- c("AWAY","WIN")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grep using a character vector with multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597559/grep-using-a-character-vector-with-multiple-patterns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `str_count` with `sum`

```
library(stringr)
sum(str_count(text, keyword))
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility using `stringr`

```r
library(stringr)

text<- "AWAYTEAM IS XXX. I THINK THEAWAYTEAM WILL WIN"
keyword<- c("AWAY","WIN")

length(unlist(str_extract_all(text, keyword)))
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>